# How can i add links and macros inside code block in confluence page?

Tags: hyperlink, macros, confluence

I need to add links and macros in code block on confluence page so that i can traverse throughout the code and describe all the fields in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know if I understood your question properly but I’ll try to answer anyway.
A code blocks in Confluence is just an “image” of what you’ve coded, a snapshot if you want, and its utility is linked to the simple enunciation of a followed procedure, a script/piece of code developed, a bug fix (just a few examples of its implementation); all code blocks that you can insert into a page are not interpreted and you can’t execute they.